# Lucene Apache doesn't keep my old index

Tags: java, lucene

I found this example in the internet:

Indexer.java

```
public class Indexer {

private IndexWriter writer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Indexer(String indexDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
    Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36), true,
            IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
}

public void close() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
    writer.close();
}

private Document getDocument(File file) throws IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    Field contentField = new Field(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, new FileReader(file));
    Field fileNameField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME, file.getName(), Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    Field filePathField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH, file.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    document.add(contentField);
    document.add(fileNameField);
    document.add(filePathField);
    return document;
}

public void indexFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Document document = getDocument(file);
    writer.addDocument(document);
}

public int createIndex(String file) throws IOException {
    indexFile(new File(file));
    return writer.numDocs();
}
```

}

Searcher.java

```
public class Searcher {
IndexSearcher indexSearcher;
QueryParser queryParser;
Query query;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Searcher(String indexDirectoryPath) throws IOException {
    Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory
            .open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);
    queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,
            LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, new StandardAnalyzer(
                    Version.LUCENE_36));
}

public TopDocs search(String searchQuery) throws IOException,
        ParseException {
    query = queryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(searchQuery));
    return indexSearcher.search(query, LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);
}

public Document getDocument(ScoreDoc scoreDoc)
        throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
    return indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    indexSearcher.close();
}
```

}

LuceneConstants.java

```
public class LuceneConstants {
public static final String CONTENTS = "contents";
public static final String FILE_NAME = "filename";
public static final String FILE_PATH = "filepath";
public static final int MAX_SEARCH = 10;
```

}

This is how I use them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    {
        // First file
        Indexer indexer = new Indexer("index");
        indexer.createIndex("f1.txt");
        indexer.close();
        Searcher searcher = new Searcher(Constante.DIR_INDEX.getValor());
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search("Art. 1°");
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
            org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
            String nomeArquivo = doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH);
            System.out.println(nomeArquivo);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-----");
    {
        // Second file
        Indexer indexer = new Indexer("index");
        indexer.createIndex("f2.txt");
        indexer.close();
        Searcher searcher = new Searcher(Constante.DIR_INDEX.getValor());
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search("Art. 1°");
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
            org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
            String nomeArquivo = doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH);
            System.out.println(nomeArquivo);
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine until the "// second file" line.

After I index my second file I'm not able to find anything in my first file.

If I create an instance of Indexer and use it this same instance to index f1.txt and f2.txt and close it then it works like I want it to be. The problem is that if I close my application and open it and decide to index another file I'd lose both f1.txt and f2.txt.

Is there a way to make Lucene always keep the previous index when it index a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using an old version of Lucene (3.6 or below), correct?

The third argument to the [IndexWriter constructor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#IndexWriter(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20boolean,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexDeletionPolicy,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength)) specifies whether it should create a new index or open an existing one.  If set to `true`, it will overwrite the existing index, if one exists in the given directory.  If you want to open an existing index without overwriting it, it should be `false`:

```
writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36), false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. And yes, I'm using 3.6.2, I'll see if I can use the current version.